# Mysql Procedure Containing Both select And Update Statement....How to call such procedure from Java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table named **notification**

> id BIGINT PK
>
> subject VARCHAR(256)
>
> send_to VARCHAR(50)           //Email id to which notification sent
>
> status TINYINT(1) default '0'  //Indicates whether notification seen
>   or not by destination

---

**Also I have a procedure to read a notification given below:**

> DELIMITER @@
>
> DROP PROCEDURE wm_request_complaint_read @@
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE wm_umis_db.wm_request_complaint_read (
>
> IN p_id BIGINT, IN p_send_to CHAR(2)
>
> )
>
> BEGIN
>
> **select rc.subject, rc.details, rc.attach_file, rc.`date`, rc.`type`,**
>   rc.sender_email
>
> **from  notification rc**
>
> **where rc.id = p_id AND rc.send_to=p_send_to ;**
>
> **Update notification set status='1' where id=p_id AND send_to=p_send_to;**
>
> END @@  DELIMITER ;

Above procedure contains both **SELECT** and **UPDATE** Statement

I am able to run above procedure from Mysql GUI tools...

but i want to run it from Java(I am using JDBC API)..

what code i should write....?

> private static final String READ_COMPLAINT_OR_REQUEST="call
>   wm_request_complaint_read(?,?)";
>
> conn=getConnection();
>
> CallableStatement cstmt=conn.prepareCall(READ_COMPLAINT_OR_REQUEST);
>
> cstmt.setLong(1, id);
>
> cstmt.setString(2, sendTo);
>
> ResultSet rset=cstmt.executeQuery();

OR

> private static final String READ_COMPLAINT_OR_REQUEST="call
>   wm_request_complaint_read(?,?)";
>
> conn=getConnection();
>
> CallableStatement cstmt=conn.prepareCall(READ_COMPLAINT_OR_REQUEST);
>
> cstmt.setLong(1, id);
>
> cstmt.setString(2, sendTo);
>
> cstmt.executeUpdate();

Answer (score 1):

What the method does internally is not important for chosing the method to call. The important thing is if it returns something or not. Since your method does not return something, `executeUpdate` should be sufficient. Use `executeQuery` if your procedure returns a result set, and `executeUpdate` if it does not. In fact `executeUpdate` will throw an exeption if you call it on a procedure that would produce a result set.

See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()

Comment: Can't i call a procedure having both(select & Update) statements using JDBC ?

Comment: Yes you can. What the method does internally is not important - the only important thing is if it returns something or not.